# UITableView not loading JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am developing a app that will load remote data in a `UITableView` but when I run it, it shows nothing. Please view and help me to debug it. Thanks

Json outPut

```
{
    "emp_info" =     (
                (
            1,
            firstname_one,
            lastname_one,
            "abcd@xyz",
            "500 B3 abc Town"
        ),
                (
            2,
            firstname_two,
            lastname_two,
            "abcd@xyz",
            "500 B3 abc Town"
        ),
                (
            18,
            firstname_three,
            lastname_three,
            "abcd@xyz",
            "500 B3 abc Town"
        )
    );
}
```

And .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    statuses=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abcd.com/My_php/result.php"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]

                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               NSLog(@"Finished with status code: %i", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                               id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];


                               NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@",jsonObject);

                               statuses=[jsonObject mutableCopy];

                               [self.theTableView reloadData];
                           }];

    NSLog(@"myURL=%@",myURL);
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[statuses count]);
    return [statuses count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    id obj = [statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text =[obj valueForKey:@"Title"];

    return cell;
}
```

And when I compile it. it shows nothing in the table infect doesn't even show the table itself.
[image: See it shows nothing]

Comment: NSLog in numberOfRowsInSection show data or not?

Comment: Well, so it's normal that it show nothing. But for me, your JSON Data is a `NSDictionary`, not a `NSArray`.

Comment: hmm Thanks but can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get NSArray contains NSArrays from NSDictionary from JSON:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
{

...

// This Array contains arrays 
   statuses=[jsonObject[@"emp_info"] mutableCopy];
   [self.theTableView reloadData];
}];
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, get value from this NSArray:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  ...
  // this is an NSArray, not an NSDictionary:
  NSArray *obj = [statuses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  cell.textLabel.text = obj[1]; // just my example
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your help ut still the same result. NO OUTPUT

Comment: After you call `[self.theTableView reloadData]`, in numberOfRowsInSection still prints 0???

Comment: Can you print NSLog of `statuses=[jsonObject[@"emp_info"] mutableCopy];` and how do you declare `statuses` variable? (Assign, strong??)

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *statuses; like this

Comment: Can you print NSLog of statuses=[jsonObject[@"emp_info"] mutableCopy];?

Comment: i NSLog statuses but it is empty ().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54596/discussion-between-nmh-and-user2966615).

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a dictionary containing an array.

If you want just the array, get the array from the value object returned by the json parser:

```
statuses=[[jsonObject valueForKey:@"emp_info"] mutableCopy];
```